# Synchronized method seems interrupted

Tags: java, synchronization

I'm writing an applet with multiple threads. I've had some strange problems an I've tracked them down to the class below. It's the entire code, no snips.

```
public class BoundingBox {
    private volatile int top;
    private volatile int left;
    private volatile int bottom;
    private volatile int right;

    public static final int IGNORE  = 0;
    public static final int TOP     = -2;
    public static final int LEFT    = -1;
    public static final int BOTTOM  = 2;
    public static final int RIGHT   = 1;

    BoundingBox(int left, int top, int width, int height) {
        this.top = top;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = left + width;
        this.bottom = top + height;
    }

    public synchronized int top()       { return top;           }
    public synchronized int left()      { return left;          }
    public synchronized int bottom()    { return bottom;        }
    public synchronized int right()     { return right;         }

    public synchronized int width()     { return right - left;  }
    public synchronized int height()    { return bottom - top;  }

    public synchronized void translate(Vector2D vector) {
        left += vector.getX();
        right += vector.getX();
        top += vector.getY();
        bottom += vector.getY();
    }

    public synchronized void alignTo(Point2D point, int hAlign, int vAlign) {
        if ((hAlign != IGNORE && hAlign != LEFT && hAlign != RIGHT)
            || (vAlign != IGNORE && vAlign != TOP && vAlign != BOTTOM))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        /// START DEBUG CODE ///
        if (right - left != width())
            System.out.println("X");
        if (bottom - top != height())
            System.out.println("Y");
        /// END DEBUG CODE ///

        int width = width();
        int height = height();

        if (hAlign != IGNORE) {
            left = point.getX();
            if (hAlign == RIGHT)
                left -= width;
            right = left + width;
        }

        if (vAlign != IGNORE) {
            top = point.getY();
            if (vAlign == BOTTOM)
                top -= height;
            bottom = top + height;
        }
    }
}
```

`X` and `Y` do print sometimes. As you can see, `width()` is defined as `right - left`, but it still happens that these two aren't equal (same with `height()`). Those four fields are private and methods are synchronized, so nothing should interrupt `alignTo`, right? Still, something does as it seems to me.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation why do X and Y print sometimes?

Comment: I think it's a symptom of some deeper problem I have to solve. `right - left` *should* be always equal to `width()`, right?

Comment: This does not explain why `X` and `Y` print sometimes, but is `vector` immutable? If not, it would be better to use `int`s as parameters in the `translate` method.

Comment: `vector` isn't immutable, but I don't change it anyway. All its methods are synchronized.

Comment: Synchronization doesn't prevent subsequent calls to `getX()` from returning two different values. This makes the `translate` method unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring top, left, bottom, right as volatile is not enough to keep them synchronized in the way that you need. The problem is, those variables are being modified on different threads using the translate method, so are changing during the execution of alignTo. You will need to put a lock on those variables for the duration of alignTo, or cache them to local variables.

Comment: That would make sense, but both `translate()` and `alignTo()` are synchronized, is it possible that both are running simultaneously in different threads?

Comment: Making a method synchronized only prevents multiple instances of that method, or synchronized children methods, being run simultaneously on different threads. Since translate is not called by alignTo, then they both can run. You could implement your alignTo method to use translate instead of setting the attributes manually, that could solve the problem.

Comment: @FriedSock Synchronized methods lock the owning object, so two synchronized methods of the same object can't be entered simultaneously.

Comment: I've changed it to use `translate()`, modified few methods to be called more safely and the issue is gone. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gronostaj but as Lone nebula and yourself criticized, translate() and alignTo() will not run simultaneously.  This answer is not correct in fact.  I bet there is other reasons for the problem you observed.